# How to pass result of a lambda expression to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I'm using asp.net mvc 5. In my model i have two tables called "User","User preferences".

In user table i have;
Id
Email
Password

In User preferences table i have
UserID
CategoryID

i need, when email is passed to the action method as a parameter,by using that email select the ID of that user & join both tables using Condition ID=UserID & pass the results to view.In the view i want to display the CategoryID of that user.
The code i tried is ;

ActionResult;

```
 public class LoggedInController : Controller

{

    private EPlannerDatabaseEntities db = new EPlannerDatabaseEntities();
    //
    // GET: /LoggedIn/
    public ActionResult Index(String email)
    {
        var Items = from m in db.Users
                    select m;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
        {
            Items = Items.Where(s => s.Email.Contains(email));

        }

        var x1 = Items.Join(db.UserPreferences, vp => vp.Id, up => up.UserId, (vp, up) => new { Id = up.UserId });
        return View(x1);


    }
}
```

}

my view is;

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApp.Models.UserPreference>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Blah</h2>

@foreach (var x1 in Model)
{

<h1>@x1.CategoryId</h1>


}
```

But when i run the program it shows the following error :

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MvcApp.Models.UserPreference]'.

what is the problem with my code??

Comment: Well yes - your result's element type is the anonymous type from `new { Id = up.UserId }` but you've said that it will be `MvcApp.Models.UserPreference`. They're not the same thing...

Comment: I recommend you to use ViewModel pattern. Create some class, make query return TypeOfYourViewModelClass and make sure that your View takes model with same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've assumed that `db.UserPreferences` contains objects of type `MvcApp.Models.UserPreference`

Try the following, the problem is becuase you were not returning the same type as your view expected

```
private EPlannerDatabaseEntities db = new EPlannerDatabaseEntities();
//
// GET: /LoggedIn/
public ActionResult Index(String email)
{
  var x1 = from m in db.Users
          where String.IsNullOrEmpty(email) || m.Email.Contains(email)
          join up in db.UserPreferences 
          on m.Id equals up.UserId
          select up;
  return View(x1);
}
```

Or if you want to maintain your existing code just change the join line to read

```
 var x1 = Items.Join(db.UserPreferences, vp => vp.Id, up => up.UserId, (vp, up) => up);
```

If the table doesnot contain `MvcApp.Models.UserPreference` you will need to change the select statement to create an object of the approriate type.

ie change the `select up` line to

```
select new MvcApp.Models.UserPreference { 
      UserId = up.UserId,
      Category = ....
}
```

Or if you use the alternative Join statement you willl need to change `(vp,up) => up` to

```
(vp,up) => new MvcApp.Models.UserPreference { 
      UserId = up.UserId,
      Category = ....
}
```

**EDIT UPDATE**

Seeing your comment to Manish Parakhiya it might be that you need to convert from the database query first to use the Mvc object.

If this is the case use my one of my first two solutions to generate `x1` (ie you are returning `up`)

then add the following.

```
var x2 = x1.ToArray().Select(up => new MvcApp.Models.UserPreference { UserId= up.UserId, Cat......});
return View(x2);
```

The `ToArray()` call will force the database query to go away and return the array of objects, you then won't get the exception.

Comment: When i return x2 it doesn't display any results..But when i return x1 it displays the right results.I think var x2= x1.ToArray.. is not needed..Anyway thank you for your support!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here problem is you are creating AnonymousType and passes it to view but in view you declared model as different type so that exception is thrown.So you must use same type declared in view as model. so you need to change your join query like following.

```
var x1 = Items.Join(db.UserPreferences, vp => vp.Id, up => up.UserId, (vp, up) => new MvcApp.Models.UserPreference{ UserId = up.UserId }).ToList();
return View(x1);
```

Comment: This throws a NotSupportedException to the code above...

Additional information: The entity or complex type 'EPlannerDatabaseModel.UserPreference' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: @ThilinaDeSilva I've added a workaround for that exception into my answer

Answer (score -2):

Just pass x1 to ViewBag

```
 ViewBag.ABC = x1
```

access this on View

```
var x1 = ViewBag.ABC;
```

Comment: Thats not a good idea to pass models through ViewBag, because you lose static type checking...

Comment: yes, but you can use this if you don't want to create other model to pass x1 data for specially for this single view

Comment: but it seems that x1 variable contains a whole model for entire view, not just some minor stuff. Its better to go with ViewModel

Comment: other way is create another model and pass it with existing model, to pass both model in a single view, like this
@model Tuple<IEnumerable<NewModel>, IEnumerable<MvcApp.Models.UserPreference>>